# Remove blue bar above navigation bar in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have implemented a Master Detail Page according to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page) but for some reason I am getting a blue bar above the navigation bar that I am not sure what is and how to remove it.

[image]

When opening the menu:

[image]

How I can remove that?

Comment: are you sure you don't have two navigation pages?

Comment: Yeah Jason might be right. How are you setting your MainPage in App.cs, or navigating to different pages?

Comment: Is my solution working for you?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have two navigationPages in your project.

In your `App.cs`, are you adding a `navigationPage` on the `MainPage` like this:

```
public class App : Application
{
    public App ()
    {
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MasterDetailPageNavigation.MainPage());
    }
}
```

This will cause the blue bar above navigation bar.

Remove it and the blue bar would disappear:

```
   MainPage = new MasterDetailPageNavigation.MainPage();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Xamarin.Forms Page constructor, add this line to hide the Toolbar

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```

From my understanding, you are using a Push to come to this page from a Login page. You might want to change your main ContentPage to be the newer Dashboard page, so

```
if (Authenticated)
    ContentPage = new DashboardPage();
```

Comment: No, I suppose this will remove both of them including the one with hamburger icon.